# OSM Reverse Geocoding - Find closest node for Coordinates

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding, graph

currently I am experimenting with Neo4j as Database for OSM Data. In the end I'd like to do routing stuff. I had a look at the Neo4j/spatial, but this is to blown up for me (not optimized for routing). Maybe I am just missing the information on how to use the spatial plugin for my already loaded OSM Neo4j database.

I need to find the closest node to given coordinates. I tried nominatim and photon, but both do not provide the ability to select the `node_type`. Is there another reverse geocoding provider that provides this feature?

Or would it be the better approach to create something like a `locationIndex` that allows me to query my own dataset?

Comment: This is a bit open - its really multiple questions that all point in different directions (e.g. neo4j, neo4j spatial extensions, nominatim / postgis, node selection, query planning) So the answer is 'it depends', and you haven't given us enough to say which factors might be relevant for you. Can you try to narrow it down, perhaps showing what you do have working, and what you want to do next. GIS.SE isn't big on open questions...

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data in a database, you could use the parser to part request and then manually search the database for the corresponding node.

With that said, however, I agree with BradHards comment above that you have asked many questions in one that are open-ended. I would highly suggest revising question into a closed-ended question.